# How to change akka-scala response model without breaking existing setup

Tags: scala, akka, microservices

I have a service A which is used by multiple microservices (internal) via a client package from this service A which includes models for MyRequest, MyResponse etc. We are using akka-scala actors, on client akka ask`?` pattern is used. This is the current system.

Now I want to add a attribute `x` in `case class MyResponse(a: Int, b: String, x: Option[String] = None)`. But when I deployed it, the services with old client stopped working and not receiving anything from service A. I want to push this change to be in non-breaking way since it is being used by multiple services, its not possible to update all of them at once. For this I have already added default value for `x`.

Need help in figuring out what is wrong here and what is the best way to publish changes like these with akka system?

Comment: Can you please add `receive` block of your old client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for my understanding : You have Server A with case class MyResponse(a: Int, b: String) and Server B with MyResponse(a: Int, b: String, x: Option[String] = None)? 
If so it sound like it's not the same message... Server B  send To Server A message it can't process (if so it will get to the dead letter Q)

If B send to A this should be the deploy steps :
1. deploy server A the new message with support for it 
2. deploy server B the new message and start using it
3. delete message from server B
4.delete message from server A

Comment: What error messages do you get so where have a direction to go.

Comment: Services with old client unable to receive messages from Service A, getting timeout errors.